# Record current webpage to file

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me how to record every web page to a text file that visitors open on my web site in PHP please?
I'm already recording the IP address, date and time.

```
<?php

function logIP()
{
     date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');
    
     $ipLog="logfile.txt"; 

     $register_globals = (bool) ini_get('register_gobals');
     if ($register_globals) $ip = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
     else $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

     $date=date ("F j, Y, g:i a");
     $log=fopen("$ipLog", "a+");

     if (preg_match("/\\bhtm\\b/i", $ipLog) || preg_match("/\\bhtml\\b/i", $ipLog))
     {
        fputs($log, "$ip - $date<br>");
     }
     else fputs($log, "$ip - $date<br>");

     fclose($log);
}

logIp();

?>
```

Comment: do you mean every route? like example.com/route1 ?

Comment: The PHP code above is called from my web page page footer file (Displays site name, copyright etc), so it's only the name of the current webpage visited that I need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

to get (log) the name of the current PHP file

So, for example, take a project structure with two pages `index.php` and `contact.php` and your logger file `log.php`:

```
/Root  
 - index.php  
 - contact.php  
 - log.php
```

You need to `require 'log.php'` in `index.php` and `contact.php` to have access to function `logIP()`.

Since you want to log the visited page, function `logIP()` must be fed with the current page as a parameter:

File: `log.php`

```
function logIP(string $page = '')
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');

    $ipLog = "logfile.txt";

    $register_globals = (bool)ini_get('register_gobals');
    if ($register_globals) $ip = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR); else $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $date = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
    $log = fopen("$ipLog", "a+");

    if (preg_match("/\\bhtm\\b/i", $ipLog) || preg_match("/\\bhtml\\b/i", $ipLog)) {
        fputs($log, "$ip - $date<br>");
        if($page !== '') fputs($log, "$page<br>"); // <----------- added page visited
    } else {
        fputs($log, "$ip - $date<br>");
        if($page !== '')  fputs($log, "$page<br>"); // <----------- added page visited
    }
    fclose($log);
}
```

I.e. file `index.php` and `contact.php` would contain:

```
<?php
require 'log.php';
logIP(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

Now everytime you visit these pages, they are logged in file `logfile.txt`

Comment: Can I parse a string value to the log.php? For example, many of my site menus are called from a DB table. How would I do something like this? 'logIP(MyStringValue)' and have it written to my text file, thru log.php?

Comment: That's a different question, you'd have to post a new question to get that resolved.